# jqgrid - columns mis-align with setGroupHeaders

Tags: jqgrid

I have an issue when my columns aren't aligned with the header only when I use setGroupHeaders. As seen in my code, I am setting the column width (as suggested in other posts). I am also using the latest version of jqgrid (just downloaded it today to see if it solves this issue).

My JS:

```
var jqadminagrid_data = [{}];
  var wwidth = $(window).width()*.90;
  var fifteen=wwidth*.06;
  var onehundred=wwidth*.16;
  var seventy=wwidth*.11;
  var sixty=wwidth*.09;
  var onetwenty=wwidth*.18;
  var fiftyfive=wwidth*.08;
  var eightyfive=wwidth*.13;
  jQuery("#jqadminagrid").jqGrid({
    url: "createadminaxml.cfm",
    datatype : "xml",
    height : 'auto',
    colNames : ['CTR Title', 'CTR Name', '', '', 'Status Date', 'End User', 'Signed By', 'Total Cost'],
    //colNames : ['CTR Title', 'CTR Name', '', 'Status Date', 'End User', 'Signed By', 'Total Cost'],
    colModel : [{
      name : 'title',
      index : 'title',
      width: onehundred
    }, {
      name : 'ctrname',
      index : 'ctrname',
      width: sixty
    }, {
      name : 'status',
      index : 'status',
      width: onehundred
    },{
      name : 'statusbutton',
      index : 'statusbutton',
      width: fiftyfive
    },  {
      name : 'date',
      index : 'date',
      width: fiftyfive
    }, {
      name : 'euname',
      index : 'euname',
      sortable: true,
      width: eightyfive
    }, {
      name : 'signed',
      index : 'signed',
      width: seventy
    }, {
      name : 'total',
      index : 'total',
      width: fiftyfive
    }],
    rowNum : 15,
    rowList : [15, 30, 45],
    pager : '#pjqadminagrid',
    sortname : 'ctrname',
    toolbarfilter : true,
    viewrecords : true,
    sortorder : "asc",
    autowidth : true,
    });
    jQuery("#jqadminagrid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
      useColSpanStyle: false, 
      groupHeaders:[{startColumnName: 'status', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: '<center><b>Status</b></center>'}]
    });

    jQuery("#jqadminagrid").navGrid("#pjqadminagrid", {
        edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false
        });
  $(window).on("resize", function () {
    var newWidth = $("#jqadminagrid").closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width()*.95;
    jQuery("#jqadminagrid").jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
    })
```

Grid with no grouping
[image: Grid with no grouping]
Grid with grouping
[image: Grid with grouping]

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you have downloaded?

Comment: I got version 5.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please, try with some other "standard" UI Theme?

We have the [same demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/grouping/group_demo/) and it is working fine. The only difference is the Theme and  and the data.

If possible can you please prepare a online demo - I think the problem is either in the Theme or in the data and the way it is inserted in the Guriddo jqGrid